# NetBeans IDE: Set project to start main class from

Tags: netbeans, project, program-entry-point

I have two projects "gui" and "plugin". When I hit "Run", i want my gui project to run. When I am working on any file in my gui project, that will work.

But currently I am working on files in the plugin project. When i hit Run, it does not find a main file (because there is none in that project). So I first need to switch the active file to any file of the gui project before I hit Run.

Is there a solution to always start the main file of the gui project although I am working in a file of the other project?

Thank you